# Is it possible to create a component for a single table row?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is it possible to create an Angular Dart component that could be used as a table row (or as tbody)? I'd like to do something like this:

```html
<table>
  <my-component ng-repeat="value in ctrl.values" param="value"></my-component>
</table>
```

Instead of quite ugly:

```dart
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="value in ctrl.values"> ...(here some td's)...</tr>
</table>
```

If not, is there any way to achieve something similar?

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: I changed my Polymer with an Angular example.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```dart
library main;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:di/di.dart';

class Item {
  String name;
  Item(this.name);
}

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'tr[is=my-tr]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    visibility: NgDirective.CHILDREN_VISIBILITY,
    applyAuthorStyles: true,
    template: '''<content></content><span>{{ctrl.value.name}}</span><span> - </td><td>{{ctrl.value}}</span>'''
)
class MyTrComponent extends NgShadowRootAware{
  @NgTwoWay('param') Item value;

  MyTrComponent() {
    print('MyTrComponent');
  }

  @override
  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    var elements = new List<Element>.from(shadowRoot.children.where((e) => !(e is StyleElement) && !(e is ContentElement)));
    ContentElement ce = shadowRoot.querySelector('content');
    elements.forEach((e) {
      e.remove();
      var td = new TableCellElement();
      td.append(e);
      print('append: ${e.tagName}');
      ce.append(td);
    });
  }
}

@NgController(
  selector: "[ng-controller=row-ctrl]",
  publishAs: "ctrl",
  visibility: NgDirective.CHILDREN_VISIBILITY
)
class RowController {
  List<Item> values = [new Item('1'), new Item('2'), new Item('3'), new Item('4')];
  RowController() {
    print('RowController');
  }
}

class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(MyTrComponent);
    type(RowController);
  }
}

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Angular playground</h1>

    <p>Custom TableRow</p>

    <table ng-controller="row-ctrl"  >
      <tr is="my-tr" ng-repeat="value in ctrl.values" param="value"></tr>
    </table>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using another tag name like `<my-component>` isn't possible because the `<table>` won't accept such tags as content, so I adapted how polymer defines extended DOM elements with the selector `'tr[is=my-tr]'`. In Angular other selectors are fine as long as the tag name is `tr`.

You can find the **project's source code** at in this [GitHub repo - angular_playground](https://github.com/bwu-dart/angular_playground/tree/master/web/table_row)

**Screenshot of the result**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Sorry I totally missed that this was Angular not Polymer. I don't know how deriving from DOM elements works in Angular.

Comment: Yep, definitively I need Angular Dart for that :-)

Comment: For a long time I had planned to try if creating a polymer element  extending a table DOM element (table, td, tr, th, ...)  works and now as you asked I thought 'just try it'. I'm very curious how to do this in Angular too but have no idea yet.

Comment: It does not look like it works for me, as tags <tr> and <td> seems to be removed when using the template. Have you tried if it works? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Please, take a look at the DOM Inspector part of the screenshot. Each row should contain 3 cells, yet it does contain only one text node with all the text crammed together.

Comment: You are right, sorry for that. Should have checked better. I'll try again.

Comment: I have changed the code of the component in the answer. Please check again - it also creates `<td>`s. I'll also check it in to GitHub in a second.

Comment: The template contains now `<span>`s so the browser doesn't drop them. At runtime I insert them into `<td>`s which are added to the `<content></content>` tag which must exist in the template.